# Creating generic hashtables - C++

Tags: .net, c++, algorithm, hashtable

.NET framework has got a *Dictionary<TKey,TValue>* class which is implemented as hash tables and provides data retrieval in constant time (O(1)). I am looking for a similar implementation in C++. I know about *std::map* but in this data retrieval takes logarithmic time. Is there any good hash table implementation in C++ which will retrieve data in constant time?

If I am writing my own, how will I calculate hash code for the key? Like .NET, I thought of having *GetHashCode()* method on types.

```
template<typename TKey,typename TVal>
class Dictionary
{
public:
   void Add(TKey key, TVal val){
       int hashCode = key.GetHashCode();
       /* .... */
   }
}
```

If I did like the above and the given key type doesn't have GetHashCode() method, compiler will throw error. But this method won't work when key is primitive types like *int*. I may need to write a wrapper for *int* by providing *GetHashCode*.

I wonder what is the C++ way of implementing this?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also, check out [C++ Technical Report 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Hash_tables) for `std::tr1::unordered_map` if a strict adherence to C++ standard is required.

Actually `std::hash_map` is not C++ standard but widely used anyway.

Comment: Note that there are two different versions of the (non-standard) `std::hash_map` around. I'd use `std::tr1::unordered_map` which is bound to become the next standard version's `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: `std::hash_map` is an SGI extension.  It's available in G++ as well, but in a different namespace (`__gnu_cxx`, I believe).

Comment: But there's also a Dinkumware version. (I think it's now in the `stdext` namespace or something like it, but it used to be in the `std` namespace so there's versions of their library out there where it is.)

Answer (score 7):

[boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/unordered.html) is probably your best and most widely portable solution at this point, if you don't have a TR1 implementation to hand.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for ready-to-use implementation, then apart from STL/TR1 and Boost hashmaps, there's also [google-sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) (it contains two implementations - one optimised for space and one optimised for speed).

If you want to write your own, then `GetHashCode` could be implemented as a separate functor, e.g.

```
template < typename TKey, typename TValue, typename THash = someDefaultHash<TKey> >
class Dictionary
{
public:
   void Add(TKey key, TVal val){
       int hashCode = THash()(key);
       /* .... */
   }
}
```

That's how [SGI's `hash_map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) does it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks promising. I will give a try.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, [std::hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)?

Note that this isn't part of the standard STL library specifications but is often available. It's in the MS libraries and the SGI libraries (as the link suggests) and in STLport.

Comment: While not truly standard, nearly every compiler the last 5 years implements one (though MSVC and G++ have slightly different semantics.)  Preference should be on unordered_map or the equivalent boost container.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you would pass a the type of a functor which has the hash function as a type parameter to the template.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using VS 2008 with the Feature Pack or service pack 1 installed, you have an implementation of TR1, which includes TR1::unordered_map.

OTOH, unless you're really creating a *huge* collection, chances are that std::map will be more competitive than you expect. In my tests, it's pretty common for the two to nearly tie, and std::map can and does come out faster fairly frequently.

Comment: In fact, often a `std::vector<std::pair<K,V> >` competes with a `std::map<K,V>`. I think there's an item for this in Meyers' "Effective STL" book (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321334876).

Comment: There is, but it only competes under rather specific circumstances. For fast lookups, the vector has to be sorted. It works nicely if things work in phases, where you collect all the data, then you can sort it, then you do searches (but rarely insert or delete after you sort). Something like map is better if you intermix insertions, deletions, and searches.

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, you summarized it very nicely.